# Is there a environmental variable for current namespace in launchfiles?

Tags: roslaunch, namespace, parameter, environment, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created an multirobot launch for Gazebo.
Now I found out that there is a solvable problem with the namespace in the robot state publisher.
I solved it with adding a tf_prefix. But now here is what I am interested in.

Is it possible to get the current namespace into the

```
 <param name="tf_prefix" value="robotA"/>
```

instead of writing the namespace name? Is there an environment variable that I could for example write something like this to get the "current namespace" for a parameter?:

```
 <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(optenv ns)"/> <!--  CAUTION: THIS IS NOT A WORKING SOLUTION  -->
```

Unfortunately robot state publisher does not care about the namespace like for example the gazebo plugins do, if you do not add an tf_prefix they add it automatically.

I also know that there is the possibility to include this by a separate launchfile and add an argument for that.

```
<!--ROBOT A-->  
<group ns="robotA" clear_params="true">
    <param name="robot_description" command=
    "$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find h4r_rapid_robot_xacros)/defs/test_robots/diff_drive_bot.xacro" />
    
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" 
          type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robotA"/><!-- Is needed, for adding the namespace to other links -->
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0"/>
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_test_bot" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" 
          args="-z 0.2 -x 0 -urdf -param robot_description -model robot_description" 
          respawn="false" />
</group>
```

[Code is here](https://github.com/Hacks4ROS/h4r_rapid_robot_xacros/blob/develop/launch/multi_diff_drive_bot.launch)

Or can I make this code (robot_state_publisher)

```
  std::string tf_prefix_key;
  n_tilde.searchParam("tf_prefix", tf_prefix_key);
  n_tilde.param(tf_prefix_key, tf_prefix_, std::string(""));
```

return the **current namespace** into tf_prefix_ somehow?

UPDATE:
I added a pull request for the robot state publisher to be able to use the current namespace as prefix, as long as there is not another approach: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/30

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212382/is-there-a-environmental-variable-for-current-namespace-in-launchfiles?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-07-04**:
Just a headsup, [tf_prefix is deprecated in tf2](http://answers.ros.org/question/124296/tf_prefix-in-fake_localization-and-move_base/). And have you looked at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/87261/launch-setup-using-tf_prefix-broken-in-hydro/)?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-04**:
Thanks for the hint @130s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A way around my problem meanwhile is:

```
<arg name="ns" default="/" /> <!-- empty strings are not allowed for namespace ! -> "/" -->
<group ns="$(arg ns)">  
    
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" output="screen"
          name="robot_state_publisher">
          <param name="robot_description" value="robot_description"/>
          <param name="publish_frequency" value="30.0"/>
          <param name="tf_prefix"    value="$(arg ns)"/>
    </node>
</group>
```

Unfortunatley this requires to have a group inside the launchfile.
But the launchfile can be used with or without namespace.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1